# Python: How to color logs while printing to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, logging, colors

A little context to what I am doing.  I am running some python scripts through a different programming language on an industrial controller. Since I am not running the python scripts directly I can't watch any print or log statements from the terminal so I need to send the detailed logs to a log file.

Since we are logging a lot of information when debugging, I wanted to find a way to color the log file such as `coloredlogs` does to logs printed to terminal.  I looked at `coloredlogs` but it appears that it can only print colored logs to files when using `VIM`.  Does anyone know a way to print colored logs to a file using python that can be opened with a program such as wordpad? (maybe a `.rtf` file).

Comment: you can put what ever color information(in plain text), then use some log viewer(like vim) to parse to colors. or just filter by key words. in fact i think log levels(Info, Error, etc) is enough.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need to install a log viewer onto the industrial controller.  The controller uses windows so I can if needed but I was hoping to use one of the native installed programs.  That being said how should I add color information to the log output?

Comment: if no color, what editor are you using to check log? notepad?

Comment: Currently I use notepad because I am not using colors.  When I start using colors I will probably use wordpad.

Comment: notepad++ can highlight common log files(and if not, find a plugin). why not have a try? you need a good editor(i'm not implying notepad++ is the best).

Comment: Notepad++ would still require me to download notepad++ (which I may do as a temporary solution) but we are trying to refrain from adding external software (installing only the software that is needed to run the code) to the industrial controllers

Comment: if industrial controllers are so important then a product with bugs shouldn't be deployed in it, right? why debug in that machine?

Comment: Testing on a desktop is different then testing on the controller.  Part of switching platforms is dealing with the bugs that come when testing on a new platform.  On top of that the debug isn't necessarily for watching when the code breaks.  It is to watch when connection or handshake failures occur over our network. Thus is why I want to solve the problem using the python logging script, not using third party software.

Comment: Do you really need a GUI tool? Of is printing the log on the console also an option (like ‘cat’ or ‘tail’ on Linux)?

Comment: @rfkortekaas Its done on windows so I can read a log file by using cmd prompt or powershell which could work. I would still need to find a good way to save the log messages to the file in such a way that powershell or cmd can color code it when it reads the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a solution to use the `Windows PowerShell` `Get-Content` function to print a file which contains `ANSI escape sequences` to color the log.

For example:

```
import coloredlogs
import logging

# Create a logger object.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Create a filehandler object
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Create a ColoredFormatter to use as formatter for the FileHandler
formatter = coloredlogs.ColoredFormatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# Install the coloredlogs module on the root logger
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')

logger.debug("this is a debugging message")
logger.info("this is an informational message")
logger.warning("this is a warning message")
logger.error("this is an error message")
logger.critical("this is a critical message")
```

When opening a `Windows PowerShell` you can use `Get-Content .\spam.log` to print the logs in color.

Comment: I think this will work for what I want.  Powershell's default color scheme isn't great but I can just use `type spam.log` in cmd prompt.  I didn't realize ANSI escape sequences can be read by Powershell and command prompt.  Thank you.